# Geofencing Hollow Location Indicator

Tags: ios

When I added a geofencing region to monitor, my app will cause the Hollow Location indicator to show non-stop on the top-right corner. Anyway to disable this? Basically I want my app to show a notification to users when they go near certain locations in the city, but the location indicator is a bit annoying...

Answer (score 0):

No, the location indicator show the user that one or more applications are monitoring their location. You cannot turn it off.